# Matplotlib: how to make imshow read x,y coordinates from other numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, imshow

When you want to plot a numpy array with `imshow`, this is what you normally do:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A=np.array([[3,2,5],[8,1,2],[6,6,7],[3,5,1]]) #The array to plot

im=plt.imshow(A,origin="upper",interpolation="nearest",cmap=plt.cm.gray_r)
plt.colorbar(im)
```

Which gives us this simple image:
[image]

In this image, the *x* and *y* coordinates are simply extracted from the position of each value in the array. Now, let's say that `A` is an array of values that refer to some specific coordinates:

```
real_x=np.array([[15,16,17],[15,16,17],[15,16,17],[15,16,17]])
real_y=np.array([[20,21,22,23],[20,21,22,23],[20,21,22,23]])
```

These values are made-up to just make my case. **Is there a way to force imshow to assign each value in A the corresponding pair of coordinates (real_x,real_y)?**

**PS:** I am not looking for adding or subtracting something to the array-based x and y to make them match *real_x* and *real_y*, but for something that *reads* these values from the *real_x* and *real_y* arrays. The intended outcome is then an image with the *real_x* values on the x-axis and the *real_y* values on the y-axis.

Comment: What do you mean? The intensities are made-up in this case - they could be anything.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html - is this what you're looking for?

Comment: No, I am not looking for something that produces a scatter plot. I am focusing on raster images (numpy arrays).

Comment: Could you share an image how it should look like? Or explain based on your two arrays how it should be "produced" (doesn't have to be code, just some explanation).

Comment: If I understand it correctly you have only 3 different `x` (15, 16, 17) and 3 different `y` (20, 21, 22) coordinates but an image of 3x4 pixels. How exactly should that work?

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Check my edit.

Comment: Will the `x_real` and `y_real` always contain the same elements, or is it also possible that `x_real = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]` (different elements in each sublist)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Setting the extent

Assuming you have

```
real_x=np.array([15,16,17])
real_y=np.array([20,21,22,23])
```

you would set the image extent as

```
dx = (real_x[1]-real_x[0])/2.
dy = (real_y[1]-real_y[0])/2.
extent = [real_x[0]-dx, real_x[-1]+dx, real_y[0]-dy, real_y[-1]+dy]
plt.imshow(data, extent=extent)
```

#### Changing ticklabels

An alternative would be to just change the ticklabels

```
real_x=np.array([15,16,17])
real_y=np.array([20,21,22,23])
plt.imshow(data)
plt.gca().set_xticks(range(len(real_x)))
plt.gca().set_yticks(range(len(real_x)))
plt.gca().set_xticklabels(real_x)
plt.gca().set_yticklabels(real_y)
```

Comment: That `extent` approach just works if the `real_x` and `real_y` are fixed-width monotonic increasing. I assume the question asks about a more *general* approach.

Comment: Imshow plots assume a monotonic 1 pixel scale, yes. Everything else would make a scale obsolete. So in case the difference between pixels is not the same over the axis range, you would need to change the ticklabels. I added a solution for just setting the ticklabels as well.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, this is about producing a raster for imshow, that is, given X - image coordinates and y - values, produce input matrix for imshow. I am not aware of a standard function for that, so implemented it

```
import numpy as np

def to_raster(X, y):
"""
:param X: 2D image coordinates for values y
:param y: vector of scalar or vector values
:return: A, extent
"""
    def deduce_raster_params():
        """
        Computes raster dimensions based on min/max coordinates in X
        sample step computed from 2nd - smallest coordinate values
        """
        unique_sorted = np.vstack((np.unique(v) for v in X.T)).T
        d_min = unique_sorted[0] # x min, y min
        d_max = unique_sorted[-1] # x max, y max
        d_step = unique_sorted[1]-unique_sorted[0] # x, y step
        nsamples = (np.round((d_max - d_min) / d_step) + 1).astype(int)
        return d_min, d_max, d_step, nsamples

    d_min, d_max, d_step, nsamples = deduce_raster_params()
    # Allocate matrix / tensor for raster. Allow y to be vector (e.g. RGB triplets)
    A = np.full((*nsamples, 1 if y.ndim==1 else y.shape[-1]), np.NaN)
    # Compute index for each point in X
    ind = np.round((X - d_min) / d_step).T.astype(int)
    # Scalar/vector values assigned over outer dimension 
    A[list(ind)] = y  # cell id
    # Prepare extent in imshow format
    extent = np.vstack((d_min, d_max)).T.ravel()
    return A, extent
```

This can then be used with imshow as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
A, extent = to_raster(X, y)
plt.imshow(A, extent=extent)
```

Note that deduce_raster_params() works in O(n*log(n)) instead of O(n) because of the sort in np.unique() - this simplifies the code and probably shouldn't be a problem with things sent to imshow

Answer (score 2):

Here is a minimal example how to re-scale the y axes to another range:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def yaxes_rerange(row_count, new_y_range):
    scale = (new_y_range[1] - new_y_range[0]) / row_count
    y_range = np.array([1, row_count - 1]) * scale

    dy = (y_range[1] - y_range[0]) / 2 - (new_y_range[1] - new_y_range[0])
    ext_y_range = y_range + new_y_range[0] + np.array([-dy, dy])
    extent = [-0.5, data.shape[1] - 0.5, ext_y_range[0], ext_y_range[1]]

    aspect = 1 / scale

    return extent, aspect


data = np.array([[1, 5, 3], [8, 2, 3], [1, 3, 5], [1, 2, 4]])

row_count = data.shape[0]
new_range = [8, 16]

extent, aspect = yaxes_rerange(row_count, new_range)

img = plt.imshow(data, extent=extent, aspect=aspect)
img.axes.set_xticks(range(data.shape[1]))
img.axes.set_xticklabels(["water", "wine", "stone"])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the extent method, to make it work, the argument aspect of imshow() needs to be "auto".